# Very basic Python functions' issue

Tags: python

I've been trying to write a function that takes values of the side of a square and evaluates it's diagonal:

```
def diagonal(side):
    return side*cmath.sqrt(2)

def main():
    diagonal(1) # Evaluating for the specific case that side = 1
```

Question #1:

- When I run the code, I don't see any output/print. Why?

Question #2:

- Is there a way to take a square root without using the `cmath` library?

When I try to take the value from the side from the user, I also see nothing (please check code below).

```
def diagonal(side):side = int(input("Side measure (integer): "))
    return side*cmath.sqrt(2)

def main():
    diagonal(1) # Evaluating for the specific case that side = 1
```

Question #3:

- a) What is wrong with the implementation?
- b) Should I ask for the side of the square **inside** the diagonal function or right after `main()`?

Thank you.

Comment: What are you expecting to see, you never `print` anything

Comment: 1. you haven't print it, 2, use Euler's method, 3. print it

Comment: ... research before asking please.

Comment: There is no `print()` - so it wont print anaything. You can use `math.sqrt()` or `number**0.5` instead of `cmath`

Comment: ([you should know the difference between `return` and `print`](Please see [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=python%20difference%20return%20and%20print%20site%3Astackoverflow.com)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, unlike in languages such as C or Java, Python isn't actually looking for a `main` function as the first point of entry into your script. So your `main` function isn't automatically executed. You need to call it outside of any function. It's good practice to have a `main` function and then some code below in this form:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This protects against inadvertently calling the main function when you import your script as a module within another script.

Second, you need to **print** to see any output. In Python 3:

```
def main():
    print(diagonal(1))
```

In Python 2 it would be `print diagonal(1)` (without brackets - in Python 2, it's a keyword, not a function)

With both those things, you should now see both the input prompt and output. But to address question 3, I would put the input prompt in your `main` function, not your `diagonal` function; this makes more sense as a division of roles. So:

```
import cmath # don't forget to import!

def diagonal(side):
    return side*cmath.sqrt(2)

def main():
    userInput = int(input("Side measure (integer): "))
    answer = diagonal(userInput)
    print(answer)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

As for question 2, I don't know, so I'd take @gonczor's answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Question #1:**

```
def diagonal(side):
    return side*cmath.sqrt(2)

def main():
    return diagonal(1)
```

**Question #2 and 3:**
Anyway, I would do this way:

```
def diagonal(side):
    return side**0.5

def main():
    side = float(input('type the side: '))
    # side =float((raw_input('type the side: ')) # this input is valid too
    return diagonal(side)
```

Code get from IDE:

```
>>> def diagonal(side):
...    return side**0.5
>>> def main():
...    side = float(input('type the side: '))
...    # side =float((raw_input('type the side: ')) # this input is valid too
...    print(diagonal(side))
>>> main()
type the side: >? 5
2.23606797749979
```

[image]

Comment: 1) The top snippet is exactly the same as the original code. 2) `input` returns a string in python 3. 3) `**2` is not the square root. 4) This still doesn't print anything...

Comment: 1) The top snippet is exactly the same as the original code --> it is not true, I added a **'return'** in the main() function. this fixes the output problem.
2) Nobody specifics which python version is using... In python2.7 it works, anyway, I fix it.
3) It's already fixed (I made a mistake)
4) When you add the 'return' in the main() function, it prints the results (in Anaconda, nobody specifics which IDE is using). In fact, you get: (1.4142135623730951+0j)

Comment: Just because one specific editor you are using is automatically printing the return value of a function does not mean that that is the default behavior - therefore this answer is plain wrong

Comment: I do not agree because the **return** sentence always gives an output, and if you run this function in a python default line command, you get out. try it!, Anyway, I fixed if it likes more this way

Answer (score 0):

Just include `print diagonal(1)` in the main method instead of just `diagonal(1)`:

```
def main():
  side = input("Side measure (integer): ")
  print (diagonal(side))
main()
```

That should be your `main()`.

Comment: for Q2 you could just import the cmath library. by #import cmath# before class declarations